# Wrapping a third party Promise into a shared Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using the AWS Amplify Auth library in my Angular app to handle authentication. This library exposes it's methods using `Promises`.

I have created a `user.service` class that is a wrapper for these to abstract it away i.e.:

```
export class UserService {

  isAuthenticated(): Promise<boolean> {
    return Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then(user => {
        ...
        return true;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        ...
        return false;
      });
  }

  getLanguageCode(): Promise<string> {
    return Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then(user => {
        ...
      });
  }
}

  getFullName(): Promise<string> {
    return Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then(user => `${user.attributes.given_name} ${user.attributes.family_name}`);
  }
```

This is all working fine but I have noticed that on startup there are multiple identical calls to AWS Cognito all requesting/receiving the same data. I believe that is because most of the methods (see my example above) are calling the Promise `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()`.

My aim was to 'share' this call if there is already one in progress so it only calls it once, and I thought that I could create Observable from the promise and share it using `private currentAuthenticatedUser: Observable<any> = from(Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().pipe(share())` and then reference this in all the functions instead, but that has caused side effects with my general flow.

Is there a way of sharing a Promise, or should I go the route of converting it into an Observable? And if so does it makes sense to make the new Observable at a class level?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can save the promise as a property and after the first call it'll be **resolved**, so next time someone will call it it'll immediately return the user object.

Something like this:

```
export class UserService {
    private currentAuthenticatedUserPromise: Promise<User>

    constructor() {
        this.setPromise();
    }

private setPromise() {
    this.currentAuthenticatedUserPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // Your http call
            Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then((user) => resolve(user))
        });
}

  isAuthenticated(forceCheck: Boolean = false): Promise<boolean> {
 If (forceCheck) {
      this.setPromise();
}

    return this.currentAuthenticatedUserPromise
      .then(....
```

Comment: thanks for that. Is it possible to reset the promise? For instance, I have the three calls going simultaneously when the app starts so I would like them to share the same promise, but if I was to call the promise again after then I would like to do a new one. Basically, I want this promise to only have one instance at a time